# Как сделать такое меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

На сайте [dba1.info](http://www.dba1.info) при наведении на меню происходит движение фона. Eсть идеи как красиво это реализовать?
Смена цвета и переход по нажатию на нужную часть страницы реализовать легко. Интересует конкретно эффект плавного движения фона в самом меню.

Comment: А что мешает посмотреть как там сделано? Включите developer tools Вашего браузера и играйте с их css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы про фон под кнопками меню.
Добавляем в каждую кнопку доп. DIV с `position: absolute` и `top: -100%`, при :hover ставим `top: 0` и через `transition` замедляем это.
Это у них так и сделано.
Разве так сложно просто посмотреть как сделано?

Answer (score 0):

Там использованы `transitions` в `css`.

У каждого элемента меню добавлено `<strong class="hover"></strong>`. Изначально каждый элемент раположен вне экрана.
При наведении мышкой на элемент меню соответвтующий `<strong>` получает другие `css` параметры. Визуально - он становится фоном элемента меню.
Ну а плавность движения сделана путем того же `css`:

```
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
```

В общих чертах думаю достаточно, чтобы докопаться до деталей.